# how to pass a code to Broadcast receiver while receiver sms delevery report in android

Tags: android, sms

I want to develop a SMS app which will send multiple SMS at a time. I want to set an id to SMS.  In SMS SENT report I want to get this id.  So, I will come to know that a particular message has been sent.

I have already added broadcast receiver.  I am receiving SMS SENT report also.

Ex: I sent 10 SMS and I got 8 SMS SENT reports. How can I tell which 2 messages are not sent so that I can resend them?

Comment: Well your idea seems good. Have you tried adding an ID?

Answer (score 0):

For every SMS (or part SMS) you send, you provide a PendingIntent. In that PendingIntent you have put an Intent, which you will receive when the SMS (or part) is successfully sent or not. In this Intent, you can put extra information using extras. So, for example, when sending the message, the code might look like this ...

```
String receiverCodeForThisMessage = "STRING_CODE_FOR_MY_SMS_OUTCOME_RECEIVER";
int uniqueCodeForThisPartOfThisSMS = 100*numberSMSsentSoFar+PartNumberOfThisSMSpart;

Intent intent = new Intent(receiverCodeForThisMessage);
intent.putExtra("TagIdentifyIngPieceOfInformationOne", piece1);
intent.putExtra("TagIdentifyIngPieceOfInformationTwo", piece2);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, uniqueCodeForThisPartOfThisSMS, intent, 0);

SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage("phonenumber", "Fred Bloggs", "Hello!", pendingIntent, null);
```

But before that, you will have registered a receiver which will get the outcome and the intent you set up; from that intent you extract the pieces of information:

```
registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Get information about this message
        int piece1 = intent.getIntExtra("TagIdentifyIngPieceOfInformationOne", -1);
        int piece2 = intent.getIntExtra("TagIdentifyIngPieceOfInformationTwo", -1);

        if (getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // success code
        }
        else {
            // failure code
        }
}, new IntentFilter(receiverCodeForThisMessage));
```

Comment: Thank u Neil, I am getting id in SENT REPORT but i have 3 problems. (1)When I inspect intent in onReceive() method it is giving same id for all messages. (2)when I get id by given key it returns -1. (3)onReceiver called two times

Comment: In reverse order ... (3) - I would expect onReceiver to be called twice if you are sending two SMS messages or a two part message. (2) Have you checked that the keys are correct .. easy to mistype them. (1) This may be beause it only actually makes one pending intent (long story), but you might find it works better if the first "0" in the create pending intent line is an integer unique to each sms (part) you send.